# Iterate through JDBC template's ResultSetExtractor without keeping references to the object (Large data set)?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Let's say I have a database table with 10,000 rows.

I simply want to iterate through each row without constructing a domain object for each row. For each row in the result set I want to invoke a method and do my own thing.

Comment: Okay, so what's stopping you?

Comment: Nothing now. Just found RowCallbackHandler should be used instead of RowMapper :)

Comment: Yes, that is a more suitable mechanism to use if you don't really intend to do any mapping.

Comment: @Kayaman Does the processRow method automatically perform a .next() type of method for each row in the result set? I noticed in the docs it says do not use .next() on the result set.

Comment: Yea, the iterating is automatic. The index parameter is provided if you need to keep track of which row you're on.

Comment: I don't see the index parameter in the processRow() method (only see the ResultSet arg0 parameter), however, I can access the int .getRow() method on the arg0 parameter.

Comment: Ah yeah, it was only `RowMapper` that passed the index.

Answer (score 1):

Use RowCallbackHandler instead of RowMapper. You can do a JDBC operation and pass through an instance of your own custom RowCallbackHandler and do whatever you would like inside the overridden method called processRow(). For each return in the jdbc operations query, this processRow() method will be called.